# Problem importing Cairo after installation in Google-Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, cairo

I successfully installed Cairo on Colab, but I receive the following error when trying to import it.

!apt-get install python3-Cairo

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairo._cairo'

I also tried to install the following packages beforehand, but the problem is not solved.

!apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev python-gi-dev libcairo2 Pycairo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install `libcairo2-dev` first.

```
!apt install libcairo2-dev
```

Then you can install `pycairo` and import it.

```
!pip install pycairo
import cairo
```